# mail server for windows 8 compatible with php mail

Tags: php

Using php 5.3 and trying to use the mail command.  I have windows 8 and want to get a pop3/smtp mail server setup so i can actually test the php mail functionality.  I'm using apache web server and IIS for my version of windows 8 doesn't come with a smtp server.

Any idea of what i should use to get this setup.

Comment: Just use Your ISPs smtp server.

Comment: i didn't buy email accounts on my high speed account... saw no need for it as i never use the ISP's accounts anyhow...

Comment: You don't need an email account you just need an smtp server name.  Whoever your isp (not hosting proivider) is should give you an smtp account to send mail out through.

Comment: if nothing esle works check out mandrill.com

Answer (score 1):

All attached is a link to Php Class that will send mail to SSL SMTP based servers with secure authentication which is pretty much every major mail server now.  I plugged this in and it worked flawlessly after i realized cut and paste removed some important backslash escapes on the strings.

http://www.kidmoses.com/blog-article.php?bid=56    Thanks KidMoses

Anyhow i dropped this in and voila it does what php mail will not do which is deal with SSL based SMTP authentication.

This one was a beast to track down.    Of course there was allot of chat about PEAR doing the same thing but after search after search i couldn't find a windows based installer for the pear module install.   Also i dare someone to try to find any information on Windows 8 SMTP Setup as SMTP is yanked from IIS 8 and i could not find one single article on how to config a SMTP server natively in Windows 8....  Microsoft is just continuing to doom itself.